# Programming a state monad in Scala

Tags: scala, monads

The theory of how a state monad looks like I borrow from Philip Wadler's Monads for Functional Programming:

```
type M a = State → (a, State) 
type State = Int
unit :: a → M a
unit a = λx. (a, x)
(*) :: M a → (a → M b) → M b
m * k = λx. 
         let (a, y) = m x in 
         let (b, z) = k a y in 
         (b, z)
```

The way I would like to use a state monad is as follows:

> Given a list L I want different parts of my code to get this list and update this list by adding new elements at its end.

I guess the above would be modified as:

```
type M = State → (List[Data], State) 
type State = List[Data]
def unit(a: List[Data]) = (x: State) => (a,x)
def star(m: M, k: List[Data] => M): M = {
 (x: M) => 
   val (a,y) = m(x)
   val (b,z) = k(a)(y)
   (b,z)
} 
def get = ???
def update = ???
```

How do I fill in the details, i.e.?

1. How do I instantiate my hierarchy to work on a concrete list?
2. How do I implement get and update in terms of the above?

Finally, how would I do this using Scala's syntax with flatMap and unit?

Comment: It would probably be easier to implement if you make your **State** a class and define `flatMap` inside it. And you can define `unit` in the companion object. - Anyways, `get` is pretty straightforward you receive an **M** and return its **State**. And `update` would be, you receive an **M** and a new **State** and you create a new **M**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your comment. What do you mean exactly by "receive an *M*". If its *M* of type M above, I don't know what is its state since it would a function. Do you mean a pair a x State?

Comment: this link explains well the use in practice of state monads in haskell https://mmhaskell.com/monads/state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `M` is defined incorrectly. It should take `a`/`A` as a parameter, like so:

```
type M[A] = State => (A, State)
```

You've also missed that type parameter elsewhere.

`unit` should have a signature like this:

```
def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
```

`star` should have a signature like this:

```
def star[A, B](m: M[A], k: A => M[B]): M[B]
```

Hopefully, that makes the functions more clear.

Your implementation of `unit` was pretty much the same:

```
def unit[A](a: A): M[A] = x => (a, x)
```

However, in `star`, the parameter of your lambda (`x`) is of type `State`, not `M`, because `M[B]` is basically `State => (A, State)`. The rest you got right:

```
def star[A, B](m: M[A])(k: A => M[B]): M[B] = 
  (x: State) => {
    val (a, y) = m(x)
    val (b, z) = k(a)(y)
    (b, z)
  }
```

---

Edit: According to @Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez:

> It would probably be easier to implement if you make your State a class and define flatMap inside it. And you can define unit in the companion object.

He suggested `final class State[S, A](val run: S => (A, S))`, which would also allow you to use infix functions like `>>=`.

Another way to do it would be to define `State` as a type alias for a function `S => (A, S)` and extend it using an implicit class.

```
type State[S, A] = S => (A, S)
object State {
  //This is basically "return"
  def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] = s => (a, s)
}

implicit class StateOps[S, A](private runState: S => (A, S)) {
  //You can rename this to ">>=" or "flatMap"
  def *[B](k: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = s => {
    val (a, s2) = runState(s)
    k(a)(s2)
  }
}
```

If your definition of `get` is

> set the result value to the state and leave the state unchanged
> (borrowed from [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad)), then you can implement it like this:

```
def get[S]: State[S, S] = s => (s, s)
```

If you mean that you want to extract the state (in this case a `List[Data]`), you can use `execState` (define it in `StateOps`):

```
def execState(s: S): S = runState(s)._2
```

---

Here's a terrible example of how you can add elements to a `List`.

```
def addToList(n: Int)(list: List[Int]): ((), List[Int]) = ((), n :: list)

def fillList(n: Int): State[List[Int], ()] =
  n match {
    case 0 => s => ((), s)
    case n => fillList(n - 1) * (_ => addToList(n))
  }
```

`println(fillList(10)(List.empty))` gives us this (the second element can be extracted with `execState`):

```
((),List(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

Comment: @Rodrigo You can chain them with `*`, like `>>=`

Comment: Thank you! Let me take a look a bit later

Comment: I actually meant something like `final class State[S, A](val run: S => A)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sorry, I'll change my answer to make it clear what you meant. I actually had `case class State[S, A](runState: S => (A, S))` at first, but then I thought I'd just use a type alias with extension methods, although I suppose using a class is more appropriate since Haskell uses `newtype` and and not `type`